# What kind of storage is IPSM?

Tags: storage

I am working with a mobile device running Android.  In addition to the common Internal shared storage, it also has an IPSM card.  Does anyone know what IPSM stands for in this context?

Comment: Hi, could you add the brand/device model for additional info? Is it [Honeywell](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/What-is-the-order-of-persist-folders-on-Internal-Storage-IPSM-and-SD-card)? According to [this forum](http://forums.thoughtsmedia.com/archive/index.php/t-12532.html), it's Intel Persistent Storage Manager.

Comment: Intel Persistent Storage Manager is the correct answer, thank you. If you want to make a formal answer I will go ahead and accept it.